# Can I use G instead of GG (short for days) if I am out of space?

Tags: english-comparison, abbreviations

I am writing a mobile app and use 1H, 1D and 7D (English), which is 1H, 1G and 7GG (Italian). That extra G is messing up my layout.

Is it ok to use 7G? I know Italians use GG for plural form of days (giorni), but I am really constrained with space.

Here is the context (market change in last 1 hour, last 1 day and last 7 days):

[image]

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!! In Italian for _giorni_ we use the lowercase format gg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [this page about abbreviations](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~ngargano/corsi/corrisp/abbreviazioni.html) the correct way to express the abbreviation of *giorni* in Italian is **gg.**

It's up to you to decide if you can stretch a point about your constraints, but the correct form is that one.

Comment: Thank you. I think it is better to use GG.

Comment: @PrimožKralj: Can't you use lower case letters? Personally, I'd find this more confusing than one or two gs.

Comment: Basically I use uppercase everywhere in the app for 9 other languages, but maybe I could use lowercase for Italian if that makes sense to Italians. After all, I am making this for them. Here is the context: http://prntscr.com/nyfq1d  

Do you still think I should use lowercase?

Comment: I'd find it neater, but I don't think it's crucial. Let's see if someone else wants to chime in. I appreciate your thoroughness, in any case!

Comment: I agree with @DaG. It's neater, but not crucial to the point that doing otherwise would compromise comprehension. I would go with lowercase only if the price to pay is not excessive. I think that the context of the app would probably clear things up if anybody had any doubts on the nature of the symbols.